# I am trying to store form information in a mysql database but it does not foward to the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I have a form and the form action= the file that contains the code below.  I am getting a connection but the data is not saving.  I formatted my form with input type textarea and the database with long text because I want to give the user as much space as they need to write their information.  I think this might be my issue and have been searching the web to see if it is but I can't find anything that says it is or not.  The weird part is that one time i did see an increase in the row of the database but when I checked it the row didn't contain the info I sent, it was blank.

```
 <?php 
    session_start();

    if (strlen($_POST['recipe'])|| strlen($_POST['usrtext'])||strlen($_POST['usrtxt'])    ='0')
    {header('location:shareerror.php');}  
    else
    {
     $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die("no connection");
    $db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection)
    or die("no connection to db");


    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood(`recipe`,`usrtext`,'usrtxt')
    VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext''$usrtxt')");

    header ('location:thanks.php'); }

    ?>
```

Comment: Can we have your code?

Comment: I don't see any code..

Comment: <?php 
session_start();

if (strlen($_POST['recipe'])|| strlen($_POST['usrtext'])||strlen($_POST['usrtxt']) ='0')
 {header('location:shareerror.php');}  
else
{
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
 or die("no connection");
 $db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection)
 or die("no connection to db");


 $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood(`recipe`,`usrtext`,'usrtxt')
 VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext''$usrtxt')");
 
 header ('location:thanks.php'); }
  
 ?>

Comment: MySQL is outdated. Think about using MySQLi

Comment: You missed a comma in your insert into code. Change it to `$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood('recipe','usrtext','usrtxt')
    VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext','$usrtxt')");`

Comment: Didn't this give you an error? Because it's a typo

Comment: imulsion's comment is misleading. PHP's mysql_ connection method is deprecated. MySQL is doing just fine.

Answer (score 1):

By mistake you are assigning instead of checking corrected statement is:

```
if (strlen($_POST['recipe'])|| strlen($_POST['usrtext'])||strlen($_POST['usrtxt']) ==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your query

```
 $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood(`recipe`,`usrtext`,'usrtxt')
    VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext''$usrtxt')");
```

change this to

```
 $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood(`recipe`,`usrtext`,`usrtxt`)
    VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext','$usrtxt')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the values for $recipe, $usrtext and $usrtxt

You are missing a comma in the values.

You are using strlen instead of isset

Also please take a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Here is the fixed code (with sql injection vulnerability intact!!)

```
 <?php 
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_POST['recipe'])|| !isset($_POST['usrtext'])||!isset($_POST['usrtxt']))
    {
        header('location:shareerror.php');
    }  
    else
    {
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
        or die("no connection");

        $db_select=mysql_select_db("smqr",$connection)
        or die("no connection to db");

        $recipe = $_POST['recipe'];
        $usrtext = $_POST['usrtext'];
        $usrtxt = $_POST['usrtxt'];

        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood(`recipe`,`usrtext`,'usrtxt')
        VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext','$usrtxt')");

        header('location:thanks.php'); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you didn't assign the variables used in the query.

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO seafood(`recipe`,`usrtext`,`usrtxt`)
VALUES('$recipe','$usrtext','$usrtxt')");
```

do that like this:

```
$recipe = $_POST['recipe'];
$usrtext = $_POST['usrtext'];
$urstxt = $_POST['usertxt'];
```

Then you can use the variables in the query

Comment: You missed a comma in the insert into query. The original query has a typo.